# How do I delete nginx?

Tags: nginx

I don't know how this program got on my machine, but it is giving me nothingn but grief.   How do I get it off my computer along with Mystart.com?  They are not in my control panel or anywhere else I have looked.

Comment: what OS? how do you know those are there? ngnix is a web server , so presumably its running as a service, or in autorun items

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

[nginx](http://nginx.opg) is a free and open source web-server.

nginx is **not** installed on your computer. A virus (a [DNS Changer](http://dcwg.org/)) is redirecting some pages you open to a alternate location, and that alternate site runs nginx. Because there is no website set up at the alternate location, you see the default 'Welcome to nginx!' page.

## Solution

Try the directions [here](http://www.dcwg.org/detect/) to see if you indeed have a DNS Changer virus, and the directions [here](http://www.dcwg.org/fix/) to remove/fix it.

### sources

[I am trying to open Facebook, Yahoo!, Yandex, Tumblr, Google etc., and instead I am getting “Welcome to nginx!” page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/welcome_nginx_facebook.html) - nginx.org

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about those particular files, but in general, on a Windows system you can simply use the desktop "search" to find the files and delete them. If these are malicious programs, though, you risk the running program doing any kind of malicious acts in retaliation, including erasing your hard drive. Better to run msconfig.exe first, click the "startup" tab, and disable anything questionable from starting up. The same goes for the "services" tab but you have to be more careful there. I remember running into viruses that had a service *and* a "startup" program in conjunction, one replacing the other if one got deleted. After disabling the evil programs from starting up, reboot, check again to make sure they're not running, and delete them. But first make a backup of all your important data... just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem start-up with Internet Explorer 9 in my Windows 7 using yahoo and google.  I did all the virus scanning with different vendors, and it did not help - even Combofix.  What finally cleared it was deleting all of my internet browser cache - passwords and all.

Answer (score -2):

Look in your computer for mira images. delete them all and it will be gone!

I used search, then went to google in my history and deleted them there too.

Comment: What are "mira images"?